# How do I change the unix time in this pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am pulling data from coingecko, and putting it into a pandas database. When I get the database back, the time is in UNIX (as expected), but I'm unsure of how to loop through to change the times.
My data is coming back looking like this, but with a lot more rows:

prices  market_caps total_volumes
0   [1623636236279, 39345.61950624865]  [1623636236279, 737114606796.8894]  [1623636236279, 40268637630.39303]

The first number is the unix timestamp and the second number is the associated price, market cap, or total volume for that time.

I have written the following function to change the timestamp, and have tested it's effectiveness with many unix timestamps:

```
def time_change(unix):
  timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix)
  date_stamp = timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  return date_stamp
```

The question, then, is how I implement this to change the unix timestamp to my new date_stamp in the entire pandas dataframe (713 rows and 3 columns). I am fairly new to this, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Input**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[[1623636236279, 39345.61950624865],
[1623636236279, 737114606796.8894],
[1623636236279, 40268637630.39303]], columns=['dt', 'px'])
df
```

**Input DF**

```
       dt           px
0   1623636236279   3.934562e+04
1   1623636236279   7.371146e+11
2   1623636236279   4.026864e+10
```

**Code**

```
df.dt = pd.to_datetime(df.dt, unit='ms')
```

**Output**

```
    dt                      px
0   2021-06-14 02:03:56.279 3.934562e+04
1   2021-06-14 02:03:56.279 7.371146e+11
2   2021-06-14 02:03:56.279 4.026864e+10
```

Comment: Though the dates are all the same here, the other values are not. One is a price, one is a market cap, and the other is the total volume. This is the big difficulty for me. I attempted to use this formula and then tried the following modified version of this for the df:

df = pd.DataFrame(market_df, columns=['date', 'price', 'date', 'cap', 'date', 'volume'])
df

This did an excellent job of naming and separating my columns. However, either way I tried it, it returned all NaN values, albeit with nice headings in the order I wanted. Any idea why that may be? I appreciate all the help.